# Maven tries to download dependency despite it existing in local repository

Tags: maven-2

I have an installed dependency in my local repository.  The remote repository where the dependency came from is now down for some reason.  When I try to compile the project Maven says that it can't resolve dependency.  But why???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maven will compare the local POM's timestamp (stored in a repository's maven-metadata file) to the remote. When maven does this depends on the updatePolicy that can be defined in your settings xml.

Either set this to never (discouraged) or skip this check (only when a remote repository appears to be down) by using the -o option (offline); then maven will not check remote repositories.

Comment: I have tried to put it in offline mode, but in that case it says, that as it is in offline mode it cant get dependency

Comment: By the way, I have solved (perhaps project is built and normally deployed) that problem by using install:install-file plugin

Comment: I'm trying to do some dev with eclipse dependencies, and because I can't find these jars, I have installed them locally and the offline option help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @michael nesterenko thanks, it also worked for me. It seems that it cached previous failure to fetch it from repository and ignored local file after that no matter what, using install plugin helped with that.

Comment: I tried both `updatePolicy` and `--offline` methods. I still get `Cannot access <XXX> in offline mode and the artifact <YYY>  has not been downloaded from it before`  or messages mentioning missing dependency. It worked after I removed the **_remote.repositories** files of maven cache.

Answer (score 28):

When you have these error, simply clean the `_remote.repositories` that indicate maven where the dependency comes from. You will find this file for each artifact inside your M2_REPO.

Comment: I tried many approaches with no luck, this is the solution finally worked. Thanks.

Comment: Life is better when shared!

Comment: Was struggling with an old project on a new machine with many legacy jars. Your tip helped. Just deleted all `_remote.repositories` files and any file with `lastUpdated` in the name and it all worked perfectly!